# I have flot rawdata that is surrounded by double quotes

Tags: flot

The rawdata is `"[[x1, y1],[x2,y2]]"`

How do I get rid of the quotes? `eval` and `JSON.parse` do not give the desired result which is `rawdata = [[x1,y1],[x2,y2]]`

Answer (score 0):

There was a problem with the data from the server. This was originally developed on a 64 bit server, but moved to a 32 bit server and the integers (actually timestamps) were truncated.

JSON.parse() does work with the quoted returned variable.